# compare keywords and metakeywords in scrapy?

Tags: web-crawler, keyword, meta-tags, scrapy

this is my spider file. Before extracting articles, i want to check if one of the keywords i give match the meta keywords of the article's link.

So this code seems to crawl but it definetly don't scrap anything as it doesn't return any items.

```
import urlparse
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from projetpfe.items import ProjetpfeItem

class ProjetpfeSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'lavieecokw'
    allowed_domains = ["lavieeco.com"]
    start_urls = ['http://www.lavieeco.com/news/economie/barid-al-maghrib-un-dialogue-social-laborieux--32385.html'] # urls from which the spider will start crawling
    rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=[r'news/\w+/\w+']), callback='parse_lavieeco', follow=True)]
        # r'\d{4}/\d{2}/\w+' : regular expression for http://telquel.ma/YYYY/MM/title URLs
    def parse_lavieeco(self, response):
        items = []
        keywords = ['barid al maghrib', 'barid al-maghrib', 'postale', 'timbre-poste', 'timbre' , 'al amana', 'poste maroc', 'barid bank', 'banque postale']
        metakeywords = response.xpath('//meta[@name="keywords"]').extract()
        if metakeywords != []:
            if any(key in metakeywords for key in keywords):
                for link in response.xpath("//a"):
                    item = ProjetpfeItem()
                    item['Titre'] = link.xpath('text()').extract()
                    item['LienImage'] = link.xpath('text()').extract()
                    item['OrganePresse'] = link.xpath('/html/head/title').extract() 
                    item['Jour'] = link.xpath('text()').extract()
                    item['Contenu'] = link.xpath('text()').extract()
                    item['Journaliste'] = link.xpath('text()').extract()
                    item['URL'] = link.xpath('@href').extract()
                    item['Categorie'] = link.xpath('text()').extract()
                    item['Annee'] = link.xpath('text()').extract()
                    outbound = str(link.xpath('@href').extract())
                    if 'http' in outbound:
                        items.append(item)
        return items
```

Comment: what have you done so far ?

Comment: i'm a newb in python, so i don't really know what i should do. i know that i have to define the keywords like that:`keyword = ["barid", "maghrib", "amana", "bank"]` and call them with `for key in keyword:` but i don't know what to write next. i just need to analyse the title (in URL) and see if it contains one of the keywords @Jithin

Comment: hi @Jithin i've just edited my post, i put in it my spider file.

Answer (score 1):

you could try something like this,

```
title = response.xpath('//title/text()').extract()
title = title[0].strip().lower() if title else ''
metakeywords = [title for _key in keywords if _key in title]
```

demo in scrapy shell,

```
In [1]: keywords = ['barid al maghrib', 'barid al-maghrib', 'postale', 'timbre-poste', 'timbre' , 'al amana', 'poste maroc', 'barid bank', 'banque postale']

In [2]: title = response.xpath('//title/text()').extract()

In [3]: title = title[0].strip().lower() if title else ''

In [4]: metakeywords = [title for _key in keywords if _key in title]

In [5]: metakeywords
Out[5]: [u'barid al maghrib : un dialogue social laborieux\u2026']
```

**EDIT**

so the complete code will be

```
def parse_lavieeco(self, response):
    keywords = ['barid al maghrib', 'barid al-maghrib', 'postale', 'timbre-poste', 'timbre' , 'al amana', 'poste maroc', 'barid bank', 'banque postale']
    title = response.xpath('//title/text()').extract()
    if title:
        title = title[0].strip().lower()
        metakeywords = [title for _key in keywords if _key in title]
        if metakeywords:
            # rest of your code if metakeywords contains title goes here
```

Comment: thank you! But i'm a newb at scrapy and python, i don't know where i should put the code you gave me...